# Hello , did anyone worked on offloading hana data into hive using pyspark?? i am facing memory issues for huge data. plz suggest

Tags: pyspark, hana

Did anyone worked on offloading hana data into hive using pyspark?? i am facing memory issues for huge data. plz suggest. I tried on smaller dataset, it was working. On huge it is giving JDBCDriverException: cannot allocate enough memory. I am using sapJDBC  driver to connect

query = select col from hana table

```
jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", driver).option("url", url).option("dbtable", query).option("user", username).option("password", password).load()

jdbcDF.write.insertInto("hive_test" + """.""" + "hive_ratings_table")
```

Comment: Please provide the exact error message incl. all details. Also, please describe the setup of your scenario in more detail. How do you access the "hive"-tables? Via HANA SDA/SDI or via your python program? And what is a "huge" data set for your system (how large is your HANA instance memory)?

Answer (score 1):

While the information about the size of the HANA instance is still missing, the error message from the HANA JDBC driver indicates that indeed HANA cannot allocate enough memory.

This is a common issue when the HANA instance is used to keep/process more data than the RAM of the HANA server allows for. The easy workaround here is to either load less data at once into memory or increase the available memory for the HANA DB. Since HANA is a in-memory database all data that is *currently processed* needs to fit into memory.

That does **not** mean that all data has to be in memory all the time, but when you want to read a large table with all columns for what is effectively a data dump then the available memory needs to support this.

"Data dumping" is particularly memory intensive as HANA has to "materialize" all records, which effectively means uncompressing the data. As long as you process the data within HANA this is usually not required.

This leaves you with a couple of options:

1. increase server memory
2. dump/load the data in batches
3. use the CSV export option (`EXPORT` command - only usable if you have access to the HANA server filesystems)
4. perform your analysis within HANA directly and don't export the data at all.

Answer (score 0):

The eaxct error says com.sap.db.jdbc.JDBCDriver exception: cannot allocate enough memory.
My schenario is I have to offload 186 millions records for a table which has 252 columns, into the hive table. I am doing it using pyspark code. Its not allowing me to take all at once. At the max it is allowing only 13 millions.

Comment: Ok, you added the additional information as answers. That's rather confusing. I recommend deleting those "answers" and instead edit your original question with the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I am using below pyspark code

query = """select * from tbalename"""
To read from HANA table
jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", driver).option("url", url).option("dbtable", query).option("user", username).option("password", password).load()

To write into Hive table
jdbcDF.write.insertInto("hive_test" + """.""" + "hive_ratings_table")

Data volume is 186 millions, To enter into pyspark shell I am using executor memory 80G, driver memory 10G, num executors 5, cores 5.